# can't install mysqlclient on centos7.3

Tags: python, mysql

when i use pip to install mysqlclient, it shows that mysql_config is not found:

```
   [root@iZus9gnp1cZ local]# pip install mysqlclient Collecting mysqlclient   Downloading http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz (89kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 13.0MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-OJR4Al/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-OJR4Al/mysqlclient/
```

After google, i find some advice to **sudo yum install python-devel mysql-devel**

but it didn't work:

```
[root@iZus9gnp1cZ local]# yum install python-devel mysql-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package python-devel-2.7.5-58.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-devel.x86_64 1:5.5.56-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.56-2.el7 for package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.56-2.el7 will be installed
Removing mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.56-2.el7 - u due to obsoletes from installed mysql-community-libs-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.56-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.56-2.el7 for package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.56-2.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

my centos version is 7.3, python 3.4.2

Comment: # yum remove mysql_community_libs
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No Match for argument: mysql_community_libs
No Packages marked for removal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall it before install mysql, it works!
I guess this command 'yum -y remove mysql57-community-release-el7-10.noarch' disrupte the environment files.